# Firebase, UIImageView and Kingfisher cache - issue with converting value

Tags: xcode, firebase, swift4, kingfisher

Im trying to implement Kingfisher image cache, with images hosted in firebase for my UITableView. However I'm having issues with converting the value types of imageView.kf.setImage..

The error I get is "Cannot convert value of type 'RetrieveImageTask' to type 'UIImageView' in coercion" this is related to the " let profileImage = imageView.kf.setImage(with: imageURL) as UIImageView" line of code below.

I don't seem to understand what imageView.kf.setImage is... I expected it to be an image within in an image view... but seems like it is something else..

```
 func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    guard let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "feedCell") as? feedCell else
    {print("dequeueResuableCell return an else"); return UITableViewCell() }


    // data fro userdataArray
    let imageURL = URL(string: userdataArray[indexPath.row].profileImage)
    let imageView = UIImageView()
    let profileImageView = imageView.kf.setImage(with: imageURL) as UIImageView
    let profileName = userdataArray[indexPath.row].name


    // data from activityArray
    let activityDate = "8 October"
    let distance = "8 km"
    let activityName = "test"
    let sightings = "20"
    let kills = "10"


    // Border styling
    // cell.addBottomBorderWithColor(color: UIColor.lightGray, width: 0.5)
    cell.clipsToBounds = true

    // Shadow styling
    cell.layer.shadowColor = UIColor.darkGray.cgColor
    cell.layer.shadowOpacity = 0.25
    cell.layer.shadowRadius = 1
    cell.layer.shadowOffset = CGSize(width: 0, height: 1) // shadow on the bottom right
    cell.layer.masksToBounds = false // important to show the shadow

    cell.configureCell(profileImageView: profileImageView, profileName: profileName, activityDate: activityDate, ActivityName: activityName , distance: distance, sightings: sightings, kills: kills)
    return cell
}
```

configureCell is in a separate view file

```
import UIKit

class feedCell: UITableViewCell {

@IBOutlet weak var profileImage: UIImageView!
@IBOutlet weak var profileName: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var activityDate: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var name: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var distance: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var sightings: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var kills: UILabel!

func configureCell(profileImageView: UIImageView, profileName: String, activityDate: String, ActivityName: String, distance: String, sightings: String, kills: String) {
    self.profileImage = profileImageView
    self.profileName.text = profileName
    self.activityDate.text = activityDate
    self.name.text = ActivityName
    self.distance.text = distance
    self.sightings.text = sightings
    self.kills.text = kills
}
```

}

Comment: I’m still trying to solve this issue, however without results so far. Still stuck on the same error,

Answer (score 1):

You can't declare profileImageView with "imageView.kf.setImage(with: imageURL) as UIImageView" because It doesn't return anything.

You need to do like this;

```
let profileImageView = UIImageView()
profileImageView.kf.setImage(with: imageURL)
```